# c++ this to write object into binary file

Tags: c++

I've some trouble with this pointer in c++ function.
I would write my class into binary file, so I write this function member

```
void Product::saveProducts(){
    fstream file;
    Product temp;
    temp.setId(-1);
    bool flag = false;
    file.open("cigarettes.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
    if(file.is_open()){
        file.seekg(0, ios::end);
        if(file.tellg()!=0){
            file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
            while(!file.eof()){
                file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&temp), sizeof(temp));
                if(temp.getId() == this->getId()){
                    flag=true;
                    file.seekp(-sizeof(temp),ios::cur);
                    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this), sizeof(temp));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!flag){
            file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this), sizeof(temp));
        }
    }
    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

But when I try to retrieve my stored object with another function member:

```
list<Product> Product::loadProducsts(){
    fstream file;
    Product temp;
    list<Product> products;
    file.open("cigarettes.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(file.is_open()){
        while(!file.eof()){
            file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&temp), sizeof(temp));
            products.push_front(temp);
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return products;
}
```

My array is filled with only one object empty. What's the problem?

Comment: file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this), sizeof(temp)); - you write only ref to object. if you object contains only POD members then you can write it to binary file and read with same system. You need use sizeof(Product) instead

Comment: You can't just dump an object to a file and read it back. You have to read/write every member individually. Tedious, but that's the only portable solution.

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the binary file to make sure they're correct? Also, what's the declaration of `Product`?

Comment: It is not necessary to flush files before closing them. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @iOS-programmer saveProducts() and loadProducsts() are member functions, and I call saveProducts() like this p.saveProducts() to save object itself.

Comment: @ClaudioPomo And what does that change?  You still can't read from a file opened for output, and opening for output still truncates the file.  Whether you do this in a member function or not doesn't change anything.

Comment: @iOS-programmer The restrictions are a lot more than you state.  Just being POD isn't sufficient; you can't write pointers, for example, and expect to do anything with them later.  And the same system isn't sufficient, the code has to be compiled with the same version of the same compiler, using the same compiler options.  (I've seen such binary files become unusable just because the compiler was upgraded.)

Comment: Please show definition of `Product` class. It probably is not (and should not be, if you are coding C++!) something you can dump to file as single write.

Comment: @JamesKanze Under "same system" I mean all factors, which you say above. For correct write to file class should have POD type + not have virtual functions. If I write something like: file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this), sizeof(Product)); then will write all included members of object, because I put sizeof(Product) - full size of object(not pointer). Of course in topic code many other mistakes.

Comment: @iOS-programmer If the class is POD, it doesn't have any virtual functions.  But it can contain other pointers (e.g. a `char const*`). (For a `Product`, of course, it's almost inconceivable that there isn't a `std::string` in there somewhere, which would mean that it isn't a POD.)  (FWIW: I've done something similar in the past.  But we defined a fixed length `char` buffer, and formatted each field as text into a fixed length record.  Which was nice, because it meant that when we migrated from Solaris on a Sparc to Linux on an Intel, there were no problems.)

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of problems with your code, starting with
the fact that just dumping bits to a file generally will not
give you anything useful that you can read back.  The fact that
you need a `reinterpret_cast` to use it should have tipped you
off.  In addition:

- You only open the file for output, and then try to read from
  it.  (Opening a file for output truncates it, so you've already
  lost all of your previous data.)
- I'm not sure what you think you're doing with `while (!file.eof())`,
  but it's surely not correct.  If for some reason, the
  `file.read` fails without hitting the end of file, you'll end up
  in an endless loop, for example.
- And you're using the results of `file.read` without verifying
  that the function worked.
- You close the file without being at the end.  This truncates
  a file open in output mode.
- Same problems in the read loop of the second snippet.  If the
  file is empty, you'll still "read" one object, pushing the
  default constructed `temp` into `products`.

Not knowing what `Product` looks like, nor the initial contents
of the file, it's hard to say what is really happening.  But
most likely:

- You truncate the file with the open.  It now has a length of
  0.
- Since `file.tellg()` returns `0`, you never even try to read
  it.  (If you'd tried to read it, an error would have been set,
  which would have made all successive operations no-ops.)
- You then write the single element, and close the file.

The only thing I'm not too sure of: in this scenario, the file
actually does contain one element.  So when you try to read it,
the first `file.read` succeeds, probably without setting
`eofbit`, since `file.read` doesn't need any look ahead.  And if
`eofbit` isn't set, I would expect you to loop a second time,
and push the unmodified bits in `temp` into `products` a second
time.

EDIT:

FWIW: *if* we assume that you're in the very restricted case
where just writing the data bits to the disk is valid (which
normally means that you'll be rereading them later in the same
process, but never from a different processs), *and* that the
`id` can never be -1 in a valid `Product`, what you probably
want to do is:

```
Product temp;
temp.setId( -1 );   //  This sort of thing should really be handled by a constructor
std::fstream file( "cigartettes.dat", ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary );
while ( file.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &temp ), sizeof(temp) && temp.getId() != getId() ) {
}
if ( file.gcount() != 0 ) {
    //      Error somewhere, we ended up reading a partial record
} else if ( temp.getId() == getId() ) {
    file.seekp( -static_cast<int>( sizeof(temp) ) );
} else {
    file.clear();
    file.flush();
}
file.write( reinterpret_cast<char const*>( this ), sizeof(*this) );
file.close();
if ( !file ) {
    //      Something went wrong somewhere...
}
```

Several comments:

- Opening in both input and output is necessary.  Opening only
  in output means that 1) the file will be truncated, and 2) any
  attempt to read it will fail.
- `file.read` will fail if it cannot read the correct number of
  bytes.  If it fails, it *might* have read some bytes anyway (and
  overwritten the id field in `Product`, and left the current
  pointer at some position which isn't a modulo of your object
  size).  So you should check for this using the value from
  `file.gcount()` (which returns the number of bytes read by the
  last unformatted read operation—in the case of the read
  you're doing, this can only be different from `sizeof(Product)`
  if the read failed.
- When specifying a negative value to seek backwards: you have
  to convert the results of `sizeof` to a signed type before doing
  the `-`.  Otherwise, you'll end up with some astronomical
  positive value, which will cause you to try to seek beyond the
  end of file (which will fail).
- When the read fails, and the number of bytes read is 0, you've
  reached the end of file.  And set the `failbit`, which will
  cause all future operations to fail.  So we have to clear the
  error if we're going to write to extend the data.  (If we
  haven't reached end of file, of course, there's nothing to
  clear.)
- When doing bidirectional input, after a read, you must execute
  either a seek or a flush before a write.  (Don't ask me why;
  it's just what the standard says.)
- Finally, it's good practice to verify the status of the file
  *after* closing, when all buffers have been fully flushed and
  passed to the OS.  If for some reason, a write has failed
  somewhere, you want to know about it, to inform the user that
  the file that was output is corrupt.

I might add that the usual way of modifying just one record in
a file is to copy the file to a new file, replacing or appending
the changed record, and then delete the old file and rename the
new.  Trying to modify a file, as you are doing, can mean that
you loose all of the data if something goes wrong.

Comment: Yes to all, but my trouble is this
`file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this), sizeof(this));`
Not write my object but only reference to it.

Comment: @ClaudioPomo No, it doesn't. `sizeof(this)` is the size of a pointer to `Product`, so you're only writing the first few bits of the object.

Comment: @ClaudioPomo That's also a problem (that I overlooked), but it's far from the only one.